# @HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name returns a different user name

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, forms-authentication

I am working on a web application using azure active directory authentication hosted in azure. When I try to display the logged in user using "@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name" it display the user email as expected. But when some other user logs in at the same time, my UI displays the other user name.
I am not caching or using static variables to retrieve the logged in user information.
I tried using the below but same issue exist. Any pointers on the issue to display correct logged in user name?

1. @User.Identity.Name
2. @HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Edit:
After analysis, I found that the issue is using [Authorize] and [OutputCache] attributes together. There is some issues in terms of caching logged in users if both are used. Any clue how to resolve the issue?

Comment: I am expecting it show the current user name who logs in but not any other user name  who logs in to same web application.

Comment: according to [the sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-1-MyOrg/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml#L7), `@User.Identity.Name` should be right.....

Comment: But when multiple users log in at the same time, the user names shows others name when I login on my machine. I am just using User.Identity.Name without storing in any variable or a static variable.
Is there any difference using using System.Security.Principal and using System.Security.Claims? I am using using System.Security.Claims. Will it cache user identity globally?

Comment: `multiple users log in at the same time -> user names shows others name` If I faced the same issue I may try to test in different browsers, like using Chrome to sign in userA and using Edge to sign in userB.. In my humble opinion, it may come from the cookie in browser... And it may also result from code. not sure about it. sorry for didn't offer any help on it...

Comment: Are you using a DI container where you are registering your objects in a wrong scope?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer here...  Let me know if it works for you too.

```
Sub CloseConn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)    
    Request.Cookies.Clear()
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
    Session.Clear()
End Sub
```

Here's the control on my masterpage:
MYMASTER.MASTER

```
<asp:LoginStatus OnLoggedOut="ClearAllData" ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" LogoutPageUrl="http://www.mysite1234.domain/" LogoutText="<%$Resources: Glossary, LogoutText%>" LoginText="" LogoutAction="Refresh" />
```